# Conditionally assemble and send emails from Excel

Tags: excel, office365, power-automate, office-scripts

I have an Office 365 with access to PowerAutomate.

In a single Office 365 Excel workbook, there are three sheets.

The first sheet "People" contains data about the recipients, including their names, emails and categories.
[image]

The second sheet has lookups, which link category with code.
[image]

And the final sheet has text of email to be sent.
[image]

What I would like to do using ***Power Automate***/**Office Scripts** is to send emails only to people for whom the category is either 2 or 3. Emails should NOT be sent to those with category 1.

The mail merge bit is to:

1. Append appropriate code for the recipient in the subject grabbed from `Sheet3!A2`. e.g. For Mack, the code would be GNG.
2. Prepend "Dear recipient name" in the email body grabbed from `Sheet3!B2`. For Mack, this would be "Dear Mack,"
3. To send emails to the correct email addresses. For Mack it should be sent to mack@company.com

I have even struggled to find any tutorials on how to use ***Office Scripts*** to send emails in Excel. So would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Comment: `For Mack, the code would be GNG.` are you sure the code is GNG instead of FCQ?

Answer (score 0):

- Office Scripts do not have the capability to send emails directly; you can utilize Power Automate for that purpose.
- The following snippet demonstrates how to compose an email.
- Implementing an `interface` is necessary to integrate with Power Automate for sending emails.

*Microsoft sample:*

> [Use Office Scripts and Power Automate to email images of a chart and table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/email-images-chart-table?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): mailItem {
  let wsPeople = workbook.getWorksheet("People");
  let wsCate = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
  let wsSubBody = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet3");
  let valuePeople = wsPeople.getUsedRange().getValues();
  let valueCate = wsCate.getUsedRange().getValues();
  let valueSubBody = wsSubBody.getUsedRange().getTexts();
  let mailItems = [] = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < valuePeople.length; i++) {
    let valCate = valuePeople[i][2];
    if (valCate === 2 || valCate === 3) {
      let sendTo = valuePeople[i][1];
      let mailSubject = valueSubBody[1][0] + " " + valueCate[valCate][1].toString();
      let mailBody = valueSubBody[1][1];
      mailItems.push([sendTo, mailSubject, mailBody]);
    }
  }
  console.log(mailItems);
}

// interface mailItem {
//   sendTo: string;
//   mailSubject: string;
//   mailBody: string;
// }
```

Comment: I think the solution is achieavable without this bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be using Power Automate only. The high-level solution would be as follows:

1. Format all 3 ranges in your Excel as tables. Unless they are table objects with names, Power Automate will not be able to identify your data.
2. Create a Power Automate flow with a button trigger.
3. Initialize a string variable for your email body template. Include the 'Dear recipient, ' part as well.
4. Use the 'List rows present in a table' action from the Excel Online Business connector to get the content of the tables (1 flow step for each).
5. Use the 'Filter' action from the Data connector to narrow your results from the first table to recipients with categories 2 and 3.
6. Use an 'Apply to Each' loop to iterate filter results.
7. Use the 'Send an Email (V2)' action from the Office 365 Outlook connector to send the emails inside the loop. For the 'To' field use the Email field of your table. For the body, build a Power Automate expression using the replace() function to substitute 'recipient' with the FirstName field.